# React Native update scroll view offset on button press

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend, scrollview, onpress

I am a beginner to react native. I would like to know how to change the scrollview's offset on pressing a button because I could not find any props for ScrollView that lets you set the scroll position.The code looks roughly like this, where scrollOffset stores the position to scroll into.and a button that represents a position.

```
const example = () => {
    const [scrollOffset, setScrollOffset] = useState(0);
    const goToOffset = (val) => {
        setScrollOffset(val);
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <Button onPress={goToOffset(width*5)} />
            <ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled >
              {
                images.map(
                    (item, index) => (
                        <Image
                            key={index}
                            source={{ uri: item }}
                            style={{ width:width/5, height:width/5, borderWidth:2, borderColor:index==active?"green":null }}
                        /> 
                    )
                )
              }
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )}
```